# Handlebars.registerHelper - Way to get content of Block?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

is there a way in registerHelper to get the content of a block?

Lets assume we have the following template:

```
{{#myif test}}thats the content i want to have{{/myif}}
```

And the following registerHelper Code:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('myif', function(test)
{
    // do something
    return <content of handlebars block>;
});
```

Many thanks!

Comment: `var myContent = options.fn(this); return myContent;`?

Comment: console.log(myContent) => undefined...

Comment: Ah okay, return works so far. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Handlebars provides the nested block to the helper as `options.fn`, where `options` is the last argument of your helper. You can invoke this block with a context object which is where that block will pick up values from.

To pass the context of the helper itself you can call it with `this`.

In this case you will probably also want `options.inverse` which is an optional block that will be used if your condition is false.

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('myif', function(condition, options) {
  if (condition) {
    return options.fn(this);
  } else {
    return options.inverse(this);
  }
});
```

And the subsequent use in the template,

```
{{#myif condition}}
  true block here
{{else}}
  else block here
{{/myif}}
```