# Using Handlebars custom helper method to hide HTML

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

I have the following custom Handlebars helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('IsNewUser', function (userId) {
    return (userId < 1);
});
```

And the following HTML in my view:

```
{{#IsNewUser Id}}
<div>
    <input name="IsActive" id="user-active" type="checkbox" checked />
    Active
</div>
{{/IsNewUser}}
```

I can clearly see the function being hit, the `userId` parameter passed correctly, and the return is `true` of type bool but instead of showing the block it shows the text 'true'.

How can I get the HTML block to hide with Handlebars without error'ing out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix it after gaining some insight from this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17632386/handlebars-registerhelper-way-to-get-content-of-block). Changed my helper method to the following:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('IsNewUser', function (userId, options) {
    if (userId < 1)
        return options.fn(this);
    else
        return options.inverse(this);
});
```